# G-suite passwords not accepted on bulk upload

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I get this back after a bulk upload of children users:

> ACTION_FAILED:PASSWORD_INVALID

I used a random generator and pasted its VALUE into the password column, so instead of

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&RANDBETWEEN(1000,9999)
```

being uploaded in the bulk .CSV I'm using `GR5485` instead.

How come the password of `GR5485` isn't accepted??

Comment: pls add more details explaining your issue

Comment: Can't expand really.
I'm trying to upload new users but the password isn't being accepted for all 55 new users. That's the only invalid return I'm getting. 
I've double checked - they're all just 6 characters of letters & numbers (not Excel formulae).
Wondered if there's a setting somewhere for the correct format of passwords?!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the password hash function [upload only] column is blank.

If there is a password hash mentioned, then the hashed password will need to be

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the passwords using a formula, make sure you copy and paste the values again on the same cells but as value only instead of the formula maybe that could resolve your matter. Maybe when you are uploading the value is not being taken but could take the formula instead, how are you managing that?